# Java merging files

Tags: java, computer-science

I want to merge 2 files to create another file named mergefile and the files have a names list but the compiler can't read my files I don't know why [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAqU5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxJmx.png)

Comment: Don't post code as screenshots, include them in question as text

Answer (score 1):

The code (as written) assumes it will be passed an argument, presumably when it was run it wasn't passed one because the screenshot shows an array index out of bounds on the line 19 - creating a file using the first argument

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot it says it has an index out of bounds exception on line 19. "index 0 out of bounds for length 0". So your args array is empty. Make sure you're passing the args when running your program.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you did not pass the argument while running the code.
You need to provide the path in the command line argument.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This answer doesn't provide more information than an already provided answer. Please add more information to the answer